# Javascript select element displayed options

Tags: javascript

I have two select box. How can I show/hide some options in one box based on text of another box?

For example, I have two box Job and Year. If I choose option Student in Job box, Year box only show  option 1 year and 2 year, and if I choose option Lecturer in Job box, Year box will show 2 year and 5 year options?

Comment: what have you tried? It would be easier to help you with examples of the code you are trying to implement.

Comment: if (document.getElementById("job").text == "Student") {
        x.remove(0);
        x.remove(0);
        x.add(option1);
        x.add(option2);
        
       }
       if (document.getElementById("job").text == "Lecturer" || document.getElementById("job").text == "Other") {
        x.remove(0);
        x.remove(0);
        x.add(option2);
        x.add(option3);
       }

Comment: edit that into your original post so you can get proper formatting :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var sel1 = document.querySelector('#sel1');
    var sel2 = document.querySelector('#sel2');
    var options2 = sel2.querySelectorAll('option');

    function giveSelection(selValue) {
      sel2.innerHTML = '';
      for(var i = 0; i < options2.length; i++) {
        if(options2[i].dataset.option === selValue) {
          sel2.appendChild(options2[i]);
        }
      }
    }

    giveSelection(sel1.value);
```

```html
    <select id="sel1" onchange="giveSelection(this.value)">
      <option value="s">student</option>
      <option value="l">lecturer</option>
    </select>
    <select id="sel2">
      <option data-option="s">1 year</option>
      <option data-option="s">2 years</option>
      <option data-option="l">2 years</option>
      <option data-option="l">5 years</option>
    </select>
```